# Apache PHP server hanging upon massed refresh

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, hanging

I have a server that I didn't setup and I know little about apart from it is way more powerful that another system stat wise but constantly freezes upon a SINGLE user just holding down F5 on the webpage.

Are there any ways to find out what is causing this? I have MySQL too.

thanks in advance for any such help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[joke]First, cut the user finger which press F5 ;-) [/joke]

You said freeze. The kernel freeze ? Then check your RAM, your logs (if any).
Apache freeze ? Increase the number of process to be able to receive more requests.

And I suggest to see too the blacklists : if a machine do more than 20 connections in 5 seconds, block it until it come back calm. See mod-evasive if you want.

Comment: mod-evasive? Right. Thanks, I need to learn these terms, I'm a total rookie when it comes to servers.

I say freeze, but the VPN to the webmin still works and responds but the webserver will not return any more results and the CPU goes up dramatically for the MySQL process

Comment: Check your PHP script to see what it can do with MySQL. Is there big request ? The MySQL requests are they mandatory ? Check MySQL optimizations, hard drives if MySQL is on disk...

Comment: OK, thanks Dom. I'm going to read through the mountain that is server documentation... *sigh*